# Google Admob not showing

Tags: flutter

I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) to display google mobile ads , my account is verified and I add my phone to the test devices, I get this message in my debug mode , but the ads aren't showing !!

> I/MediaCodec(28957): setCodecState state : 0 W/AudioTrack(28957): Use
> of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
> W/AudioTrack(28957): See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to
> use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your
> playback use case

Code :

```
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        // Change Banner Size According to Ur Need
        size: AdSize.mediumRectangle,
        adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
        listener: BannerAdListener(onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print("Failed to Load A Banner Ad${error.message}");
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        }),
        request: AdRequest())
      ..load();
    //Interstitial Ads
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: AdHelper.interstitialAdUnitId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          this._interstitialAd = ad;
          _isInterstitialAdReady = true;
        }, onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          print("failed to Load Interstitial Ad ${error.message}");
        }));
  }

  /** Dispose Ads */
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    _interstitialAd.dispose();
  }
```

then I use this code to display the ad

```
GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              //Load the ad
                              //update the image
                              ff(imageList[index], widget.image.path)
                                  .then((value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  finalsd = value;


                              _isInterstitialAdReady
                                  ? _interstitialAd.show
                                  : null;
                                });
```